# Negative Number in fillRect()

Tags: java, applet

I am using a negative number to have `fillRect()` go the opposite way. It works well on my computer, but my friends cannot see it working properly. What do I do?

```
page.fillRect (12, 12, -5, 10);
```

Comment: What OS you and your friends are using ? With which Java versions ?

Comment: I am using Windows, my friends are using Windows. My friends are using the latest Java (he had to install it on his computer to see it). I was using eclipse. It worked, so I uploaded it to my website, and it worked on both chrome and firefox even after I did a hard refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you and your freind are using 2 different versions of Java. your supports fillrect with a negative value and your freind's doesn't. (or even sdk vs jre).

what that shows is that you should write this a different way to have your applet run on all versions.

why not simply move your x of -5 ?

if you want to do it in a more neat way

```
public void myfillRect(graphics page, int x, int y, int width, int height){
    if(width <0)
        x-=Math.abs(width);
    if(height <0)
        y-=Math.abs(height);

    page.rectfill(x,y,Math.abs(width), Math.abs(height));
}
```

Comment: Okay, so its a bar graph, so I want it to go towards the negative direction.

Comment: With the solutions I poster it will do that. instead of asking it to paint a rectangle backwards, you'll simply be painting it forwards but from further back thus giving you the same effect. am I missing another issue ?

Comment: helped and be helped ^^. (the "deserve" a green mark makes me think of the gold stars system you have in kinder garden :P)

Comment: There is, of course, no need to abs the dimensions twice; adding the negative amount will have the same effect: `if(width<0) { x+=width; width=-width; }` is more efficient and just as clear.

Comment: I know I originally put a quicker/shorter version if(width<0)x+=width... but then I realized it might be confusing the logic I was explaining, so I preferred a clearer version.

Answer (score 2):

There are two schools of thought on this.

One is that any polygon with a negative dimension is nonsensical and should not be rendered - what do you mean it's -10 pixels wide??

The other is that a negative dimension simply inverts the polygon on that dimension's axis.

Most painting systems apply the latter logic.  My experience in painting with Java has always been this, though I would not often have had negative dimensions, so my experience might not count for much.

As to what you can do:

1. You might need to have your friend update his Java version.
2. Otherwise you must perform the inversion yourself, by checking for a negative dimension and transposing your x,y origin in order to make the dimension positive.  That is, the rectangle [10,10,-5,5] is spatially equivalent to [5,10,5,5].  The negative dimension is added to the origin coordinate, and then made absolute.  Note, this can result in a negative origin, but hopefully the drawing system is not *quite* that messed up.

Personally, I would prefer to require a newer JVM, if possible.

Otherwise my recommended code would be:

```
public void fillRect(Graphics gc, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    if(width <0) { x+=width;  width =-width;  }
    if(height<0) { x+=height; height=-height; }
    gc.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
    }
```

Also, note that you'll need similar for other drawing operations.

Lastly, I would be suspicious of another mistake in all this, since the behavior is very surprising - I would simplify everything down to a minimal test program, with debug output and verify before wrapping a crap load of painting primitives.

Comment: That is actually my goal. I am inverting it so it goes the opposite direction.

Comment: I think the logic of not supporting negative pixels is stupid but this example shows that not all versions are the same unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Just indicating a small issue in Lawrence code that appear when you drag up the rect which give wrong height value.

The problem is in the row

```
if(height<0) { x+=height; height=-height; }
```

and it has to be y not x

```
if(height<0) { y+=height; height=-height; }
```

in total:

```
public void fillRect(Graphics gc, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    if(width <0) { x+=width;  width =-width;  }
    if(height<0) { y+=height; height=-height; }
    gc.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
}
```